# understanding multi-touch statement - pointer ID/index

Tags: java, android

```
    int action = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
    int gIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)>>
                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    int gID = event.getPointerId(gIndex);
        switch (action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:    
                y[gID]=(int)event.getY(gIndex);
                break;
```

thisis a fragment of a code to get y and print it in a text view.
But there is something that makes no sense to me...
in this line of code

> y[gID]=(int)event.getY(gIndex);

with this i assigning the y value of gIndex to y[in the possition of id]
BUT how i known i am reffering to the same "finger" gIndex can move it value any time or the system just known that i whant to known y position of gIndex based on Id thats all...

Answer (score 0):

First off-  you're using some old code.  Its better not to mask yourself and use the unmasking functions.

```
action = event.getActionMasked();
gIndex = event.getActionIndex();
```

Secondly, if you want to get the y for a given pointer id you use

```
y = event.getY(event.findPointerId(pointerid));
```